# How to remove elements from a document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

Is there a way to iterate through a document and remove all `<:p />` elements if they don't have any runs?
I am trying to remove paragraphs if they look something like this:

```
<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1" />
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="0" />
            <w:numId w:val="0" />
        </w:numPr>
        <w:ind w:left="432" />
    </w:pPr>
</w:p>
```

Here is what I have so far, but it only removes empty `<w:p />` elements.

```
foreach (Paragraph P in D.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where(x => !x.HasChildren).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call this :

```
foreach (Paragraph P in D.Descendants<Paragraph>()
         .Where(o=>o.Descendants<Run>().Count() ==0).ToList()
```

But keep in mind if you have sections in your document, it may causes problems (check this for more information : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.sectionproperties(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Is there way to also see if the paragraphstyle has a value of `Heading1`?

Comment: yes sure! check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.paragraphstyleid(v=office.14).aspx , but if your problem remains ,asked it in another thread. Also OpenXml Sdk has a tool that can help you much!

Answer (score 1):

I would load the xml into an XmlDocument and then use linq:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\Path\To\Xml\File.xml");

var rootNode = doc.DocumentElement;

XmlNodeList ps = rootNode.SelectNodes("//p");
for (int i = 0; i < ps.Count; i++)
{
     if (ps[i].SelectNodes("//pr").Count == 0)
     {
         rootNode.RemoveChild(ps[i]);
     }
}
```

That code is completely untested though, but it does compile. Let me know if this isn't any good for you and check out do some googling of Xml Parsing!

Answer (score 0):

i'm using Linq,
This can do better.

```
/*parent is the document body*/
parent.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where(p=>p.Descendants<Run>().Count()==0).All(p =>
{
   p.Remove();
   return true;
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.